# Why does Gitlab do not show a project network graph and other graphs for my imported repo?

Tags: gitlab

I have migrated cvs repo with cvs2svn240 and git fast-import1834 into a git repository. Also I have installed Gitlab53 and imported my git repo. So I can browse through files, add users and so on. Everything works fine. The only thing is that I always get blank graph pages.

System: RHEL63, 65GB RAM, 4 CPU cores.
Git-Repo: 2,8 GB (bare).

I have not yet create new commits on the repo, it is still in after migration state. But I think it should show graphs based on the current repo data.

Where could be my problem?

Answer (score 1):

This could be because of the size of the repo.
There is a [pending issue 4218](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4218) "Large Scale Project Graph Problem" which reports a similar problem (lack of content in the graphs)

[image: no graph]

---

As [geerlingguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100134/geerlingguy) add [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254806/why-does-gitlab-do-not-show-a-project-network-graph-and-other-graphs-for-my-impo/18263417#comment34484423_18263417), that issue is now close, and geerlingguy [opened a ticket](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/5678818-build-cache-graphs-for-large-repositories).

Comment: Sadly, that issue is now closed, but I don't think anything ever came of it.

Comment: @geerlingguy ok. I have included a link to your ticket in the answer for more visibility.